# Why won't this link open a file anymore?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, websphere, href

I have a Web application that is hosted locally on Websphere.  In the application there is a link to a .doc file located on a windows server.

```
<a href="K:\TTMS\ATeam\Misc_Regular_Reports\MTeam\Output\CIT.doc" target="_blank">CIT</a>
```

The link was been working for years, but suddenly stopped working on all computers on the network.  When I click the link, nothing happens.  I checked the files path and name, and nothing has changed.  The interface is viewed using IE8.

Does anyone have any clues onto why this isnt working or where I can look to resolve this?

edit: i have just noticed that the file (CIT_.doc) has been saved in the same directory, could this have an effect on it?

Comment: Well, what do you mean "stopped working"?

Comment: @bricker nothing happens when I click the link, the link is on 2 different pages, and neither opens the file anymore

Comment: Bear in mind that browser settings also make a difference when deciding what to do with files. IMO a direct link like this is brittle to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd imagine one of the following has occured:

- The file has been moved or renamed
- The K: drive has been re-mapped or other wise modified to a different location
- A popup blocker is tampering with the link (because `target="_blank"`)

In other words you need to manually check that file location within explorer, you also need to try a different browser.

Also you need to change the link to:

`<a href="file:///K:/TTMS/ATeam/Misc_Regular_Reports/MTeam/Output/CIT.doc" target="_blank">CIT</a>`

[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) for the reason, you *may* also need to [URLEncode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) it.

Comment: the file name and path are the same, nothing has changed

Comment: @Mike - So you can navigate to the file on exactly the same path? (i.e. you've copy and pasted the href value into explorer?). Also try holding down the Ctrl key whilst clicking (in case of popup blocker).

Comment: yeah, exactly, and there is no popup blocker that i am aware of, holding CTRL and clicking doesnt change anything

Comment: yeah, there isnt a popup blocker that i am aware of, holding CTRL and clicking doesnt change anything

Comment: With the recent IE security changes, I had to add the webapp to the trusted sites list.  This solved the problem.  Thank you all that helped.

Comment: Glad you found the answer, this is the reason I said to try different b
rowsers you would've got the answer sooner :-)

Answer (score 2):

It probably has something to do with security settings that your network administrator has recently setup, seeing as the m.edmondson's answer does not work. Try it in another browser besides IE.

Comment: i tried in Firefox and got this error `Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (k) isn't associated with any program.`

Comment: Try to [reset the settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737), it should solve your problem.

Comment: Firefox has given you the clue - you need to tell it to use the file:/// scheme

Comment: @m.edmondson i changed the code and it still wont work, there must be something wrong with the files permissions